# How to count of the number of unique values that occur in the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

> But there are several constraints

1. cannot create any other data structures such as arrays, strings, etc.
2. Cannot modify the array passed to method as the parameter and lastly,
3. Cannot perform sorting or rearranging array element values.

> I have written this solution but it modifies the array passed to method as the parameter.

```
public int countUnique(int[] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    int[] temp = arr;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(temp[i]==Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            continue;
        }
        int tempVal = temp[i];
        for(int j=0 ; j<arr.length; j++) {
             if(tempVal==temp[j]) {
                temp[j]= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }
        result =result+1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Here is one example**

```
 1. countUnique({1, 0, 1, 0, 1})
 2. expected result : 2
 3. my resuly : 2
 4. expected array after method call : {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}
 5. array after method call : {-2147483648, -2147483648, -2147483648, -214748364...}
 6. error : incorrect parameter value(s) after method call
```

Comment: If you can't use any other data structure why are you using `Map`?

Comment: You included the code for `countDuplicates()` but the output of `countUnique()`. If the question is about `countUnique()`, you should post that method instead.

Comment: Please clear up and clarify your question, explain why you are using map when it is not allowed and how the array can be changed when your code doesn't modify it for instance.

Comment: sorry copied wrong code

Comment: Map is a data structure. In your code you are using it and you said you cannot use it.

Comment: Now this is my code eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple count.

Use nested `for` loops.

The outer loop iterates over each element in the array `arr[i]`, while the inner loop iterates over all the elements before the `i`'th element. If there was element in the inner loop that already seen before, we don't count it (by setting the `duplicate` flag to true), otherwise, we count it (`count++`).

Note that we stand in all constraints:

1. Used only 1 int valriable, `count`.
2. The array wasn't modified.
3. No sorting or rearranging was done.

```
 public int countDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        boolean duplicate = false;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(!duplicate)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
 }
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem @Omri

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient solution would be to add all elements to a `HashSet` and return the size of the `HashSet`. That would take `O(n)` time. However, you are not allowed to use "other data structures".

Without a `Set`, you can use a nested loop to find the number of unique elements in `O(n^2)` time.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    boolean unique = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (unique) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

**Explanation:**

For each element of the array (having index `i`), you iterate over all the elements having a smaller index and check whether that element already appeared for some index `j` < `i`. If it did not, you increment your count of unique elements.

Or you can use an `IntStream` (but you are probably not supposed to):

```
return Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count();
```

Comment: @Andreas my bad. Thanks!